# Hexadecimal to Bytes in Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm working on a Word file manipulator (DOCX format to be specific) and it is working fine but at this phase I'm expected to take a file from SAP software, I take the file in the form of bytes that look something like `504B030414000600080000002100DFA4D26C5A0100002005000013000`.

However I try to use this code to read the bytes received, put them in an input stream and open them with Apache POI's functions:

```java
byte[] byteArr = "504B030414000600080000002100DFA4D26C5A01000020050000130008025B436F6E74656E745F54797065735D2E786D6C20A2040228A0000200000000000000".getBytes();
InputStream fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArr);
return new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fis));
```

The last line brings me an error that the file gives isn't OOXML.

How to transform my received bytes to something relevant in Java?

Comment: Are you sure "504B030414000600080000002100DFA4D26C5A0100002005000013000" [...] in the code block is the content of the .docx file?

Comment: The value "504B..." is the hexadecimal representation of bytes. Convert the hexadecimal string into bytes.

Comment: @JonathanDavidArndt yees it is a file that contains only 2 words in English.

Comment: @SandraRossi yes thats exactly what I did in the code unless you mean something else I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Using `getBytes` is for the `String` type. Because this is hexadecimal, you will have to use `DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary`.

*This question has more information, and even more options to choose from:*
[Convert a string representation of a hex dump to a byte array using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/140131/2657515)

---

Now, having said that, I have not been able to convert the hex string provided from your question into a good document.

Running this function:

```
    try (final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/", "Test Document.docx")))
    {
        final byte[] b = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(
                "504B030414000600080000002100DFA4D26C5A01000020050000130008025B436F6E74656E745F54797065735D2E786D6C20A2040228A0000200000000000000");
        fos.write(b);
    }
```

... results in the file below:

[image]

The `[Content_Types].xml` in there is promising (if you open other valid documents with 7-Zip you will see that in the archive). However, I cannot open this file with MS-Office, LibreOffice, or 7-Zip.

If I had to guess, I would say this particular file has become corrupted, or parts of it gone missing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , yes I do suspect something is off with the file now although i told the client to check and he says it is the same and even sent me a the file itself, So i will keep looking in this data converter since  i did not know about it before. Thank you